# Why is my function inside a function considered undefined in this case

Tags: javascript, function, debugging, undefined

My function addSpace produces an array of arrays with each index being a string. I seem to have an error latter with my function first; the computer says that undefined is not a function. I have looked for the bug, but have not found it. This is part of a larger amount of code. And this part of the code is not finished yet. The error is not with "drawTable", but with the function "first".

```
var drawTable = function(){
  var ret = addSpace();
  var table, i;
  var retFirst = "";
  var first = function(){
    for(i = 0; i < ret.length; i++){
      var a = ret[i][0].join();
      console.log(a);
      retFirst = retFirst + a;
      console.log(retFirst);
    };
    return retFirst;
  };
}
console.log(drawTable());
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Where do you get the error? Did you try using the debugger to see what is undefined?

Comment: `drawTable` doesn't return anything, thus `undefined`

Comment: The error was with the function first. Thanks for that clarification. I am not done with drawTable, but drawTable does not have the error. It is the function inside drawTable.

Comment: drawTable returns nothing, so "undefined" is the correct value. I think that you want to execute the first function inside the drawTable function.

Comment: The function drawTable is not done, yet, but the error came when I tried to console.log(first).

Comment: But `first` is only defined within `drawTable`.  So unless the `console.log(first)` was *inside* the `drawTable` function definition, `first` would be undefined.

Comment: But drawTable did not produce undefined when it was used with console.log

Comment: Where are you calling `first`?

Comment: Why function assignments rather than declarations? Anyhow, *first* is not called. What does *addSpace* return?

Comment: My error was resolved when I finished my function holding the function "first". Thanks, everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simplified example:

```
 function someFunction() {
     var anything = "I am defined!";
 }
 someFunction();
 console.log(anything);
```

The above will result in `undefined` because `anything` is only defined within the body of `someFunction`, not outside it, even after the function is called.

In your case, `someFunction` is `drawTable` and `anything` is `first`.